# Prove a subset of $C^0$ is closed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove that the set $ A= \{ f \in C[-1,1]:( f(1)+f(-1)+ \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=0)\} $ is closed.

I've already noticed that all the odd functions belong to it and I thought of considering a sequence of functions in $M$ that converges to a function of $M$, but I really don't know which one could do the trick.

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Under what topology do you consider $C[{-}1,1]$? Uniform convergence?

Comment: What can you say about the map $f \mapsto f(1) + f(-1) + \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx$?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Prove that each of the functions, $f\mapsto f(-1)$, $f\mapsto f(1)$ and $f\mapsto\int_{-1}^1fdx$ are continuous.